# How do I auto click a button using document.querySelectorAll jscript

Tags: javascript

I have a web page that has a list of various items. I go into this location regularly to empty it out by inputting 0 in a quantity field and then clicking an "update quantity" button, this process is/has to be done item by item.

I can't figure out how to have the script execute item by item  i.e. input zero for item a, update the quantity, go to next item and repeat.

Inspecting the "update quantity" button displays this -
`<input type ="text" name="quantity" value="1" size='3">`
, so i'm unable to use a getElementsById.

Here is what my script looks like now -

```
function emptylocation()
  {
  var quantities = document.getElementsByName("quantity");
  for (var i = 0; i < quantities.length; i++)
    {
    quantities[i].value = 0;
    }
  document.querySelectorAll("button[type='submit']")[0].click();
}
```

Comment: What does the accompanying HTML look like?

Comment: This is what I see the "update quantity" button - input type ="text" name="quantity" value="1" size='3". Is this what you mean?

Comment: you are not using a form? otherwise you cannot repeat an identical name in your input fields, only the last field will be taken into account, and how much form do you use ?

Comment: Not quite. But it might be okay. It's customary to include the HTML javascript will operate on in the question itself, as it exists in the page. I had been expecting HTML for a bunch of buttons and inputs. If you do this, we wont be expected to guess. ;)

Comment: Ah okay, my apologies - But, yes the page does have a bunch of buttons and inputs. All of the "update qty" buttons have the same properties: input type =  "submit" name="update" value="update qty" size="10". Same as the fields: input type ="text" name="quantity" value="1" size='3"

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>


function emptylocation(event)
{
  event.preventDefault()

  var quantities = document.getElementsByName("quantity");
  for (var i = 0; i < quantities.length; i++)
    {
    quantities[i].value = 0;
    }
}

</script>

<form>
  <input type ="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="3"/>
  <input type ="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="3"/>
  <input type ="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="3"/>
  <button type="submit" onclick="emptylocation(event)">update quantity</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: I am trying to use this, but I keep getting this error message: eslint: null - parsing error :unexpected token <... I am using Tampermonkey